# Performance of method overloading

Tags: c#

Ok, maybe that is not the smartest question but I cant get my head around it. I was wondering about the performance of method overloading. Here is a simple example that illustrates my question:

```
class testadd
{
    public double _a { get; set; }
    public double _b { get; set; }
    public double add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    public double add()
    {
        return add(_a, _b);
    }
}
```

If I now have an instance of this class and call add(), like this:

```
        var tadd = new testadd();
        tadd._a = 1;
        tadd._b = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(tadd.add());
```

Doesn't that need two method calls, first add() and then add(double a, double b)? If you have a more extensive method this is a lot neater because I dont have to retype the function body but if it costs performance this might still not be the way to go. Or does the compiler figure this out and I dont need to worry about this?

Comment: Have you tried to run both (without printlines) in a huge loop with a Stopwatch ? To decompile the result code ?

Comment: Don't make members of what should be parameters. This question also has nothing to do with overloading, your `add()` could as well be called `foo()`. The question is whether an extra method in the call chain has a noticeable performance impact. Even if it has, what are you going to do about it?

Comment: Sorry but can you elaborate on your first part pls? I m not an expert. What I can do about it, well I could simply copy the function body into both methods to save one call

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that CIL that C# compiles to is very explicit in which method it calls, so there is no run-time cost in working out which version of a method should be called.

The costs and benefits of overloading are entirely semantic; they make a class' public surface more or less understandable to a human by either (if used well) being clearly understood as variants of the same operation where the difference between them can be reasonably guessed at and is documented to back that up (especially in the case where one is a variant with a "default" value for another), or else (if used badly) give different operations the same name.

The next thing to note is that small, simple* methods can expect to be inlined, so the cost of calling `tadd.add()` will (in a release build, anyway) be pretty much the same as the cost of calling `tadd.add(tadd._a, tadd._b)` directly. This would hold even if `_a` and `_b` were `private` and so calling that form directly wouldn't be allowed: the `private` is a restriction on what the C# code can do, not on what the compiler or jitter can do. It also has the benefit that if `tadd` was a field it would only load the field once, rather than three times.

One reason for overloading can actually be as a micro-optimisation in that if we have `Foo(int a, int b, int c)` and `c` is `0` for the majority of calls then adding `Foo(int a, int b) => Foo(a, b, 0)` can reduce the size of calling methods and so sometimes make them more likely to be inlined in turn. That is very definitely a micro-optimisation though not worth doing for its own sake most of the time. 99.9% of the time you overload it should be because it makes code clearer. The 0.1% should be measured to be sure it actually did help in a hot path. (I'm still saying the costs and benefits of overloading are entirely semantic above, because in the cases where this does help it would have helped just as much to have called that method something else, overloading has no performance impact in itself).

*"simple" is not necessarily a simple thing to determine though, and "small" is relative, but anything that makes a single call, not wrapped in implicit or explicit `try` blocks, not virtual and not working on large value types is very likely to be inlined.